# can't run zipalign.exe in mac

Tags: macos, ionic-framework

I have recently moved from Windows to Mac. I am now trying to package my ionic app using a mac.  I am getting an error when trying to run the following command:

```
zipalign.exe -v 4 android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk MyApparmv7.apk
```

Here's the log from the terminal:

```
Leos-MacBook-Air:apk leoc$ ls
android-armv7-debug.apk         jarsigner.exe
android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk  my-release-key.keystore
android-x86-debug.apk           zipalign.exe
android-x86-release-unsigned.apk
Leos-MacBook-Air:apk leoc$ zipalign.exe -v 4 android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk MyApparmv7.apk
-bash: zipalign.exe: command not found
```

I found one suggestion to include "./" at the start of the command but I got the same problem.  By the way, the zipalign.exe came from my windows machine - not sure if this causes the problem because I was able to run the jarsigner.exe from my windows machine in my mac.  I also cannot find the zipalign.exe in my mac after installing Eclipse.

Comment: You are trying to run a _windows_ executable on _macOS_ which is unix based? Maybe start somewhere more basic than programming.

Comment: yeah, I'm quite new to unix which is why I mentioned that I tried running the jarsigner.exe from my windows machine and it worked.  I just don't know how to get hold of the zipalign for mac if the windows version is not valid.

Comment: @Dmitry , I saw that.  However, I still have the same problem even if I add the "./" before the zipalign.  Also, if I run the command find . -name "zipalign.*" from the root folder, the zipalign.exe that I transferred from windows is the only one that appears.

Comment: Did you try without `.exe`?

Comment: yes.  I tried both with the same result.  really weird problem....

Comment: ok, I looked at the solution again and when I changed the find command to find . -name "zipalign", I found that there is a file in the android folder. thanks for your help.